# compile time conditions in if statements

Tags: c, if-statement

If I had an `if` statement with a condition that can be evaluated at compile time, would the compiler remove the whole `if` if the condition evaluates to false like this:

```
if (1 < 0) { puts("hello"); }
```

or just remove the check if the `if` condition evaluates to true:

```
if (0 < 1) { puts("hello"); }

/* just becomes */ 
puts("hello");
```

Comment: probably every modern compiler will (at least I do not know any which will not despite the optimisation level)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is permitted to perform any optimizations as long as the observable behaviour of the resulting program matches that of the C abstract machine.

In other words: yes, the standard allows **but does not require** `if (condition) { block; }` to be replaced by either `{}` or `{ block; }` if `condition` can be determined at compile-time to always evaluate to `0` or non-`0` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Almost every compiler I've seen will evaluate arithmetic and comparison operators whose operands are integer constant expressions, so as to yield integer constant expressions, and will optimize out conditional branches based on constant-zero or constant-non-zero conditions.  On many compilers, this may be used to facilitate compile-time assertions via constructs like:

```
if (WOOZLE >= 23)
{
  extern void woozle_isnt_a_constant_less_than_23(void);
  woozle_isnt_a_constant_less_than_23();
}
```

On compilers where that construct is usable as a static assert, the function call *and all reference to the identifier `woozle_isnt_a_constant_less_than_23`* will be optimized out if WOOZLE is a compile-time integer constant less than 23, and thus the linker will have no reason to care about whether that function exists.  Some other compilers I've used, however, will include the reference to the function whether or not it is called, resulting in link errors if it does not exist.